# Как в WordPress зарегистрировать и добавить выпадающее при наведении меню?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, bootstrap

Есть сайт на WordPress, где в тему хочу добавить `bootstrap` меню с выпадающим списком при наведении. Регистрирую меню стандартным способом:

```
<?php 

register_nav_menus(array(
'top'    => 'Верхнее меню'
));

wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse', 
    'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
    'theme_location'=>'top'
) );
?>
```

Затем хочу перенести в него функционал этого меню, но есть проблемы с добавлением в ссылку классов `class="dropdown-toggle"` атрибутов `data-toggle="dropdown"` и во внутренний список `ul` класса `dropdown-menu`. Как это можно сделать? [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/ydcMQ/1220/)

```css
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="padding:15px 15px;">Название проекта</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Меню
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Меню
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a id="drop1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Меню
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нужно использовать класс `Walker`, следующий код при добавлении в `function.php`, добавляет нужные классы к пунктам меню и ссылкам внутри него, при этом стандартные классы меню wordpress не выводятся.

```
class mainMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    // назначаем классы li-элементу и выводим его
    $class_names = ' class="main-menu_item"';
    $output.= '<li' .$class_names. '>';

    // назначаем атрибуты a-элементу
    $attributes.= !empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' .esc_attr($item->url). '" class="main-menu_link"  ' : '';
    $item_output = $args->before;

    // проверяем, на какой странице мы находимся
    $current_url = (is_ssl()?'https://':'http://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $item_url = esc_attr( $item->url );
    $item_output.= '<a'. $attributes .'>'.$item->title.'</a>';


    // заканчиваем вывод элемента
    $item_output.= $args->after;
    $output.= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }
}
```

И в шаблоне где выводиться меню, выводим его следующим образом:

```
<?php $main_menu = new mainMenuWalker (); ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                                    'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
                                    'container' => 'nav',
                                    'container_class' => 'main-menu',
                                    'menu_class' => 'main-menu_list',
                                    'menu_id' => 'menu-header',
                                    'walker' => $main_menu
                                )); ?>
```

В этом варианте конечно классы добавляются напрямую, без использования массива `classes` и у вложенного меню у тега `ul` генерируется дефолтный класс `sub-menu`.
Если же необходим более тонкий контроль, то еще немного расширим класс `Walker`:

```
class mainMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    //для начала зададим класс для вложенного пункта меню тегу ul
    //функция start_lvl формирует превую строчку в шаблоне вывода списка, это нам и нужно.
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"my-class\">\n";// указываем нужный нам класс, теперь все вложенные теги ul будут иметь указанный класс.
    }
    // если необходимо обозначить тег li, что он является родительским элементом вложенного списка модифицируем немного функцию display_element.
    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
        //получим  id элемента пункта меню
        $parent_elem = $this->db_fields['id'];
        // проверим есть ли в нем вложенный список
        if ( !empty( $children_elements[ $element->$parent_elem ] ) ) {
            // запишем в массив classes необходимый нам класс и присвоим элементу списка
            $element->classes['parent_class'] = 'parent-item';
        }
        Walker_Nav_Menu::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }
  //Ну а здесь уже приведем в нужный нам вид классы li элемента
  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    // назначаем классы li-элементу и выводим его
    //для этого добавим наш класс в массив classes
    $item->classes['my_class'] = 'main-menu_item';
    // и напрямую укажем какие классы из массива мы хотим использовать.
    $class_names = ' class="' .esc_attr( $item->classes['my_class'] .' '. $item->classes['parent_class'] ). '"';
    $output.= '<li ' .$class_names. '>';

    // назначаем атрибуты a-элементу
    $attributes.= !empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' .esc_attr($item->url). '" class="main-menu_link"  ' : '';
    $item_output = $args->before;

    // проверяем, на какой странице мы находимся
    $current_url = (is_ssl()?'https://':'http://').$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $item_url = esc_attr( $item->url );
    $item_output.= '<a'. $attributes .'>'.$item->title.'</a>';


    // заканчиваем вывод элемента
    $item_output.= $args->after;
    $output.= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }
}
```

**PS**
Eсли хотим использовать все классы и дефолтные, указываем просто массив `$item->classes`

тогда строка будет иметь вид:

```
$class_names = join( ' ', $item->classes );
$class_names = ' class="' .esc_attr( $class_names ). '"';
$output.= '<li id="menu-item-' . $item->ID . '"' .$class_names. '>';
```

Можно воспользоваться фильтрами и отсортировать классы так как нам нужно

Несколько ссылок по теме:
[Может оказаться полезной](https://truemisha.ru/blog/wordpress/nav-menu-walkers.html)
[Кодекс (англ)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)
[wp-кама](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_nav_menu)
[еще статья из wp-кама](http://wp-kama.ru/id_140/polzovatelskoe-menyu-v-wp-30-wp_nav_menu.html)

Comment: где-то чего-то не хватает, т.к. выбивает 500 ошибку, если я хотя бы дописываю эту строку, то получаю уже хотя бы просто белую страницу
      `private $open_submenu_on_hover;

  function __construct($open_submenu_on_hover = true) {

     $this->open_submenu_on_hover = $open_submenu_on_hover;

    }`

Comment: Не совсем понятно с каким участком приведенного мной примера возникают проблемы?